# Save body of a streaming future object to disk

Tags: rust, closures, rust-tokio, amazon-polly, rusoto

I'm using the [PollyClient](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_polly/struct.PollyClient.html) from [rusoto](https://github.com/rusoto/rusoto), where I'm attemping to handle what I believe is a `Future` response of some type from the method `synthesize_speech()`.

Here is a snippet of what I have that compiles and runs as-is:

```rust
extern crate rusoto_core;
extern crate rusoto_polly;

use std::default::Default;
use tokio::{io};

use rusoto_core::credential::{ProfileProvider, ProvideAwsCredentials};
use rusoto_core::Region;
use rusoto_core::ByteStream;
use rusoto_polly::{PollyClient, SynthesizeSpeechInput, Polly};
use std::fs::File;
use futures::AsyncBufRead;
use std::pin::Pin;
use futures::Future;

fn main() {

    let region = Region::UsEast1;
    let polly_client = PollyClient::new(region); // using default credenetials

    let speech_input = SynthesizeSpeechInput{
        engine: Option::from(String::from("neural")),
        language_code: None,
        lexicon_names: None,
        output_format: "mp3".to_string(),
        sample_rate: None,
        speech_mark_types: None,
        text: String::from("hello world!"),
        text_type: None,
        voice_id: String::from("Amy")
    };
    let mut response = polly_client.synthesize_speech(speech_input);

    println!("Now how to we handle this respones object...");

}
```

My goal is to save what should be MP3 binary data in the response.  I have not shared any of the compiler errors, as I've gone through quite a few different ones.  I'm brand new to Rust, and while was progressing with non-async code, this was my first encounter with it.

Do I need to wrap that `synthesize_speech()` method in a closure, such that I could wrap that in some kind of `await` block?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is just a toy example, but after mimicing some of the tokio `async` pattern on `main()` from the [rusoto documentation](https://github.com/rusoto/rusoto#usage), was able to get this to work:

```rust
extern crate rusoto_core;
extern crate rusoto_polly;

// use rusoto_core::credential::{ProfileProvider, ProvideAwsCredentials};
use rusoto_core::{Region};
use rusoto_polly::{PollyClient, SynthesizeSpeechInput, Polly};
use std::fs;

#[tokio::main] // https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.2/tokio/attr.main.html
async fn main() {

    let region = Region::UsEast1;
    let polly_client = PollyClient::new(region); // using default credentials

    let speech_input = SynthesizeSpeechInput{
        engine: Option::from(String::from("neural")),
        language_code: None,
        lexicon_names: None,
        output_format: "mp3".to_string(),
        sample_rate: None,
        speech_mark_types: None,
        text: String::from("Hello world, from Rust!"),
        text_type: None,
        voice_id: String::from("Amy")
    };

    match polly_client.synthesize_speech(speech_input).await {
        Ok(output) => match output.audio_stream{
            Some(audio_stream) => {
                println!("{}", audio_stream.len());
                fs::write("mp3/rstts.mp3", audio_stream).expect("Unable to write file");
            },
            None => println!("audio stream not found"),
        },
        Err(error) => {
            println!("error: {:?}", error);
        }
    }
}
```